# Can I clear cell contents without changing styling?

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to clear the contents of multiple cells, but without changing the background/font properties of the cells?

I am currently using `Range("X").Cells.Clear` but its removing my background color and I would prefer not to have to "repaint" it on each clear.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You should use the [ClearContents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb178828%28v=office.12%29.aspx) method if you want to clear the content but preserve the formatting.

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:G37").ClearContents
```

Answer (score 21):

you can use [ClearContents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa223828%28v=office.11%29.aspx). ex,

```
Range("X").Cells.ClearContents
```